# Generate A Random String With A Set of Banned Substrings

Tags: string, algorithm, random, time-complexity

I want to generate a random string of a fixed length `L`. However, there is a set of "banned" substrings all of length `b` that cannot appear in the string. Is there a way to algorithmically generate this parent string?

Here is a small example:

I want a string that is 10 characters long -> XXXXXXXXXX
The banned substrings are {'AA', 'CC', 'AD'}
The string ABCDEFGHIJ is a valid string, but **AA**BCDEFGHI is not.

For a small example it is relatively easy to randomly generate and then check the string, but as the set of banned substrings gets larger (or the length of the banned substrings gets smaller), the probability of randomly generating a valid string rapidly decreases.

Comment: Please, have a look at **Aho - Corasick algorithm** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm which can efficiently check if *any* of banned substring is in the string. You can even check the *partially generated* string to break early

Comment: Is it important for you that the random string follows a uniform distribution? Or is it okay to follow a different random distribution if that helps the generation algorithm be simpler?

Comment: You can find an efficient algorithm on CS.SE at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/115518/755.

Answer (score 7):

This will be a fairly efficient approach, but it requires a *lot* of theory.

First you can take your list of strings, like in this case `AA`, `BB`, `AD`.  This can trivially be turned into a regular expression that matches any of them, namely `/AA|BB|AD/`.  Which you can then turn into an Nondeterministic Finite Automaton (NFA) and a Deterministic Finite Automaton (DFA) for matching the regular expression.  See [these lecture notes](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Emoss/610-slides/05.pdf) for an example of how to do that.  In this case the DFA will have the following states:

1. Matched nothing (yet)
2. Matched `A`
3. Matched `B`
4. End of match

And the transition rules will be:

1. If `A` go to state 2, if `B` go to state 3, else go to state 1.
2. If `A` or `D` go to state 4, else go to state 1.
3. If `B` go to state 4, else go to state 1.
4. Match complete, we're done.  (Stay in state 4 forever.)

Now normally a DFA is used to find a match.  We're going to use it as a way to find ways to **avoid** a match.  So how will we do that?

The trick here is [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

What we will do is create a table of:

```
by position in the string
    by state of the match
        how many ways there are to get here
        how many ways we got here from the previous (position, state) pairs
```

In other words we go forward and create a table which starts like this:

```
[
    {1: {'count': 1}},
    {1: {'count': 24, 'prev': {1: 24}},
     2: {'count': 1, 'prev': {1: 1}},
     3: {'count': 1, 'prev': {1: 1}},
    },
    {1: {'count': 625, 'prev': {1: 576, 2: 24, 3: 25}},
     2: {'count': 25, 'prev': {1: 24, 3: 1}},
     3: {'count': 25, 'prev': {1: 24, 2: 1}},
     4: {'count': 3, 'prev': {2: 2, 3: 1}},
    },
    ...         
]
```

By the time this is done, we know exactly how many ways we can wind up at the end of the string with a match (state 4), partial match (states 2 or 3) or not currently matching (state 1).

Now we generate the random string backwards. First we randomly pick the final state with odds based on the count.  Then from that final state's `prev` entry we can pick the state we were on before that final one.  Then we randomly pick a letter that would have done that.  We are picking that letter/state combination completely randomly from all solutions.

Now we know what state we were in at the second to last letter.  Pick the previous state, then pick a letter in the same way.

Continue back until finally we know the state we're in after we've picked the first letter, and then pick that letter.

It is a lot of logic to write, but it is all deterministic in time, and will let you pick random strings all day long once you've done the initial analysis.

Comment: How efficient is this?

Comment: If there are `m` strings of length `k` then the original NFA creation is `O(mk)`, the DFA construction is usually `O(mk)` but can be as bad as `O(m^k)` in time and space.  The dynamic programming problem is `O(n s)` where `s` is the size of the DFA.  The actual random choice is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

1. Random String is created while repeating until the ban string does not appear.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int N = 1110000;

char ban[] = "AA";
char rnd[N];

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int n = 100;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) rnd[i] = 'A'+rand()%26;
        rnd[n] = 0;
    } while (strstr(rnd, ban));
    cout << rnd << endl;
}
```

I think this is the easiest way to implement.
However, this method has complexity up to `O((26/25)^n*(n+b))`, if the length of the string to be created is very long and the length of the ban string is very small.
For example if `ban="A", n=10000`, then there will be time limit exceed!

2. You can proceed with the creation of one character and one character while checking whether there is a ban string.

If you want to use this way, you must know about KMP algorithm.
In this way, we can not use the system default search function `strstr`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int N = 1110000;

char ban[] = "A";
char rnd[N];

int b = strlen(ban);
int n = 10;

int *pre_kmp() {
    int *pie=new int [b];
    pie[0] = 0;
    int k=0;
    for(int i=1;i<b;i++)
    {
        while(k>0 && ban[k] != ban[i] )
        {
            k=pie[k-1];
        }
        if( ban[k] == ban[i] )
        {
            k=k+1;
        }
        pie[i]=k;
    }
    return pie;
}


int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    
    int *pie = pre_kmp();
    int matched_pos = 0;
    for (int cur = 0; cur < n; cur++) {
        do {
            rnd[cur] = 'A'+rand()%26;
            while (matched_pos > 0 && ban[matched_pos] != rnd[cur])
                matched_pos = pie[matched_pos-1];
            if (ban[matched_pos] == rnd[cur])
                matched_pos = matched_pos+1;
        } while (matched_pos == b);
    }
    
    cout << rnd << endl;
}
```

This algorithm's time complexity will be O(26 * n * b).
Of course you could also search manually without using the KMP algorithm. However, in this case, the time complexity becomes O(n*b), so the time complexity becomes very large when both the ban string length and the generator string length are long.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Using the first approach can get very slow.  Using the second approach creates biased matches.  For example 1/26 of the time you'll get `A` as the first letter because that guess can always find a way through.  But in fact you should get `A` as the first letter strictly less than `1/26` times.

Comment: Keep in mind `bits/stdc++.h` isn't portable.

Comment: Please check my code again. The first letter can never be 'A'.

Comment: have you tried codeforces? I am an icpc wf medalist. <bits/stdc++.h> is portable across all code contest sites (codeforces, codechef, hacker rank, topcoder).

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

Create a map where the keys are the banned substrings excluding the final letter, and the values are the lists of allowed letters. Alternatively you can have the values be the lists of banned letters with slight modification.

Generate random letters, using the set of allowed letters for the (b-1)-length substring at the end of the letters already generated, or the full alphabet if that substring doesn't match a key.

This is O(n*b) unless there's a way to update the substring of the last b-1 characters in O(1).

---

Ruby Code

```
def randstr(strlen, banned_strings)
  b = banned_strings[0].length # All banned strings are length b

  alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a

  prefix_to_legal_letters = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = ('a'..'z').to_a}
  
  banned_strings.each do |s|
    prefix_to_legal_letters[s[0..-2]].delete(s[-1])
  end
  
  str = ''
  
  while str.length < strlen
    letters_to_use = alphabet
    if str.length >= b-1
      str_end = str[(-b+1)..-1]
      if prefix_to_legal_letters.has_key?(str_end)
        letters_to_use = prefix_to_legal_letters[str_end]
      end
    end
    str += letters_to_use.sample()
  end
  
  return str
end
```

A silly example to show this works. The only legal letter after 'a' is 'z'. Every 'a' in the output is followed by a 'z'.

```
randstr(1000, ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'aj', 'ak', 'al', 'am', 'an', 'ao',
'ap', 'aq', 'ar', 'as', 'at', 'au', 'av', 'aw', 'ax', 'ay'])

=> "gkowhxkhrknrxkbjxbjwiqohvvazwrjxjdekrujdyprjnmbjuklqsjdwzidhpgzzmnfbyjuptbpyezfeeydgdkpznvjfwziazrzohwvnitnfupdqxivtvkbazpvqzdzzsneslrazmhbjojyqowhvjhsrdgpbejicitprxzmkhgsuvvlyfizmhohorazemyhtbazvhvazdmnjmjzoggwmjjnrqxcmrdhxozbsjjdqgfjorazmtwtvvujpgivdxijowgxnkuxovncnivazmtykliqiielsfixuflfsgqbpevazozfsvfynhxyjpxtuolqooowazpyoukssknxdntzjjbqazxjttdblepsjzqgxmxvtrmjbgvuyfvspdrrohmtwhtdxfcvidswxtzbznszsqorpxdywbytsitxeziudmvlnluwmcqtfydxlocltozovhusbblfutbqjfjeslverzctxazyprazxzmazxwbdfkwxdwdqxnqhbcliwuitsnnpscbsjitoftblgjycpnxqsikpjqysmqiazdazwwjmeazxcbejthnlsskhazxazlrceyjtbmcpazscazvsjkqhiqfbjygjhyqazsbjymsovojfxynygzwmlhkmpvswpweqkkvmbrxhazpmiqrazcgprlbywmqpyvtphydniazovrkolzbslsosjvdqkgrjmcorqtgeazfwskjuhndszliiirtncmzrzhocyazyrhhpbcsmneuiktyswvgqwkzswkjnyuazggnreeccyidvrbxuskrlchjxnrrpljilogxmicjvmoeequbpkursrqsisqtfkruswnyftdgbjhwvcrlcnfecyfdnslmxztlbfxjhgeslqedrflthlhnlwopmsdjgochxwxhfhvqcixvxdjixcazggmexidtlhymkiyyfuhxufvxyfazmmwsbrlooqwfphgfhvthspvmyiazdazggpeuhnpjmzsazfxmsukpd"
```

Note that this code and approach needs modification if the OPs statement that all banned substrings are length b is modified -- either directly (by giving banned substrings of varying lengths), or implicitly (by having a (b-1)-length substring for which every letter is banned, in which case the (b-1)-length substring is effectively banned.

The modification here is the obvious one of checking all the possible key lengths in the map; it's still O(n*b) assuming b is the longest banned substring.

Comment: What if the substrings have repeated letters?

Comment: @גלעדברקן It works fine if substrings have repeated letters. The keys aren't sets, but are the (b-1)-length substrings. So if AAB and AAC are banned then we'd have AA -> {everything but B, C} in our map, and whenever the last two characters we generate are both 'A', we exclude 'B' and 'C' from eligible successors.

Comment: Say we have banned substrings, "aa", "ab", "ac"..."az" and my first letter in the generated candidate string is "a?"

Comment: @גלעדברקן You'd talking about a scenario where there's effectively a banned substring of length b-1. This probably doesn't come up for the OP since he says all banned substrings are length b, but it's trivial to detect such a substring and ban it as well. Where there are multiple lengths of banned string we need to check all lengths in our map. This can still be done in O(n*b).

Comment: Oh, I missed the part that the banned substrings are a fixed, equal length.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I wrote code & gave some sample output.