# Why is vector<vector<int>> slower than vector<int> []?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I was trying to solve leetcode323. My code and my way to solve the problem was basically identical to the official answer. The only difference was that I was using `vector<vector>` while the official answer used `vector []` to keep the neighbors of each node. When I used `vector []`, the system accepted my answer. Is there any advantages of using `vector []` over using `vector<vector>`? I put my code and the official solution code below. Thank you so much in advance.

My code:

```
class Solution {
    public :
    void explore(vector<bool> & visited,vector<int> nei[],int cur){
        visited[cur]=true;
        for(int i=0;i<nei[cur].size();i++){
            if(!visited[nei[cur][i]]){
                explore(visited,nei,nei[cur][i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
public:
    int countComponents(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges) {
        vector<bool> visited(n);
       vector<vector<int>> neighbors(n);
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<edges.size();i++){
            neighbors[edges[i][0]].push_back(edges[i][1]);
             neighbors[edges[i][1]].push_back(edges[i][0]);
        }
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(!visited[j]){
                count++;
                explore(visited,neighbors,j);
            }
        }
        return count;

    }
};
```

Official solution

```
class Solution { 
public: void dfs(vector<int> adjList[], vector<int> &visited, int src) { 
visited[src] = 1;    

for (int i = 0; i < adjList[src].size(); i++) {
        if (visited[adjList[src][i]] == 0) {
            dfs(adjList, visited, adjList[src][i]);
        }
    }
}

int countComponents(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
  
    int components = 0;
    vector<int> visited(n, 0);
    vector<int> adjList[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        adjList[edges[i][0]].push_back(edges[i][1]);
        adjList[edges[i][1]].push_back(edges[i][0]);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (visited[i] == 0) {
            components++;
            dfs(adjList, visited, i);
        }
    }
    return components;
}
};
```

Comment: When you asked this question on the LeetCode forums, what answers did you get?  Was it mentioned that the official solution is not valid standard C++ code?

Comment: Did you try profiling the code?

Comment: I'd prefer `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` vs. `std::array<std::vector<int>,  N>` - the fixed size stack allocated array version doesn't have the overhead of dynamic allocation for its elements.  If you also didn't create the `vector<vector<int>>` with the correct number of elements from start (or `reserve`), you also have the cost of reallocation.

Comment: Offtopic: performance measurements on leetcode sucks. I've seen when same code was run multiple times factor between fastest and slowest run was of order `3`!

Comment: The task description is hidden behind a paywall. Please provide at least input constraints.

Comment: I would say that VLA (even if invalid C++) "allocation" is faster than real allocation needed by `std::vector`.

Comment: Lol the "official" solution uses a VLA, which pretty much every decent programmer avoids. Its not even possible to run the "official" solution on every valid c++ compiler. That's why these sites are terrible.

Comment: `vector<int> adjList[n];` -- This is not even valid C++ code, and this is called the "official solution"???

Comment: `vector<int> adjList[n];` -- Well, this is prima facie evidence of how worthless learning C++ using leetcode really is.  All of the participants who got the "correct answer" using this syntax will now believe they have conquered the question using C++.  They now walk into a C++ interview with confidence, and start to use this syntax in a question being asked them, and get surprised when they are rejected almost immediately.  Then they will say "but leetcode says this was valid and I even used it in one of their toughest questions.  What happened?".

Comment: @Paul: For your amusement, [the response from a self-proclaimed competitive medalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104620/generate-a-random-string-with-a-set-of-banned-substrings#comment132537055_75104847) after someone had the temerity to suggest that `<bits/stdc++.h>` isn't portable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think the main problem of your solution is [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) which is special case of `std::vector`.

In the '90s memory size was a problem. So to save memory `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization of `std::vector` template and single bits are used to store `bool` value.
This compacts memory, but comes with performance penalty. Now this has to remain forever to be compatible with already existing code.

I would recommend you to replace `std::vector<bool>` with `std::vector<char>` and do not change anything else. Let implicit conversion between `bool` and `char` do the magic.

Second candidate is missing `reserve` for `adjList[i]` as mentioned in other answer, but "official" solution doesn't do that either.

Here [I refactor your code](https://godbolt.org/z/nPeMzYhxG).

Answer (score 0):

> The only difference was that I was using `vector<vector<int>>`

There are several differences:

- Official uses (non standard C++) VLA, whereas you use compliant `vector<vector<int>>`.

  I would say that VLA "allocation" (similar to [`alloca`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html)) is faster than real allocation from `std::vector` (`new[]`).
  From your test, assuming timing is done correctly, VLA seems to have a real impact.
- Official use `vector<int>` whereas you use `std::vector<bool>`

  With specialization, `vector<bool>` is more compact than `std::vector<int /*or char*/>` but would require a little more work to set/retrieve individual value.
- You have some different names.

  Naming difference should not impact runtime.
  In some circonstance, very long difference and template usage might impact compilation time. But it should not be the case here.
- Order of parameters of `dfs`/`explore` are different.

  It might probably allow micro optimization in some cases, but swapping the 2 vectors doesn't seem to be relevant here.

> Is there any advantages of using `vector []` over using `vector<vector>`?

VLA is non standard C++, that is a big **disadvantage**.
Stack is generally more limited than heap, so size of "array" is more limited.

Its advantage seems to be a faster allocation.

The usage speed should be similar though.